# Python Django prevent duplicate in Many-to-many fields

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have 3 classes in my models.py-

```
class Nx2FwComponent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Nx2FwComponentWithPath(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Nx2FwComponent)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Nx2FwConfig(models.Model):
    nx2FwComponentWithPaths = models.ManyToManyField(Nx2FwComponentWithPath)
```

I have created a list object to add to the Nx2FwConfig table-

```
(Pdb) nx2CompList
[<Nx2FwComponentWithPath: V:\rels\mba\mba>, <Nx2FwComponentWithPath: v:\rels\mfw\mfw>]
```

The problem I'm having is I want the "Nx2FwComponentWithPath" many-to-many field to be unique lists i.e in below I should not be allowed to add nx2CompList twice-

```
(Pdb) nx21 = Nx2FwConfig()
(Pdb) nx21.save()
(Pdb) nx21.nx2FwComponents.add(nx2CompList[0], nx2CompList[1])
(Pdb) nx22 = Nx2FwConfig()
(Pdb) nx22.save()
(Pdb) nx22.nx2FwComponents.add(nx2CompList[0], nx2CompList[1])
```

Is it reasonable to ask for uniqueness in many-to-many sets? Can you please suggest a better way of implementing this ?

Answer (score 2):

use a custom model for your ManyToMany Relation

```
class Nx2FwComponent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Nx2FwComponentWithPath(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Nx2FwComponent)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class Rel(models.Model):
    nx2FwConfig = models.ForeignKey('Nx2FwConfig')   
    nx2FwComponentWithPath = models.ForeignKey(Nx2FwComponentWithPath)

    class Meta:
         unique_together = ('nx2FwConfig', 'nx2FwComponentWithPath')

class Nx2FwConfig(models.Model):
    nx2FwComponentWithPaths = models.ManyToManyField(Nx2FwComponentWithPath, through=Rel)
```

but Maybe what you want is  (the `unique` in path seems indicate that):

```
class Nx2FwComponent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Nx2FwComponentWithPath(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Nx2FwComponent)
    nx2FwConfig = models.ForeignKey('Nx2FwConfig')         
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    class Meta:
         unique_together = ('nx2FwConfig', 'name')

class Nx2FwConfig(models.Model):
    nx2FwComponents = models.ManyToManyField(Nx2FwComponent, through=Nx2FwComponentWithPath)
```

Comment: Can you please show me how to create an membership object using the first custom model ?